# Laravel: How I can I execute a javascript code only after a user has logged in?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.4. I want to execute some javascript code only after a user has logged in.

My problem statement is - I want to execute some javascript code to listen for user notifications (I am using pusher for broadcasting). The channels for notifications will user ID based; so I can't use generic code.

What would be the most elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using Laravel Echo?

Comment: Not as of now; would using it do the trick? I understand I'd still need the user id for binding to the channel?

Comment: You can have public and private channels (private are the channels that require auth). With Echo, this is handled for you. Then when you want to subscribe to a private channel and you're not logged in you can simply wrap the connection logic in an if statement but even if you don't the connection won't be allowed because of the auth.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this to the controller?

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: I am using the middleware in the routes. But how would using this snippet in controller help me with the javascript part? Sorry I'm very new to laravel so you wold need to explain it further.

Answer (score 0):

You can check is user login in your blade file and add javascript for members.something like this in your view file :

```
@if(\Auth::check())

 <script .... />

@endif
```